# issue with destroy using rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails v4.2.4 bit having an issue with the destroy call on a model called post.  Config and code copied below as well as log output.  Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

**index.html.erb**

```
  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= post.title %></td>
        <td><%= post.body %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Ar
e you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
   # flash[:success] = "Post deleted"
    respond_to do |format|
      flash[:success] = "post was deleted"
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
    redirect_to_posts_url
  end
```

**routes inside config directory**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
 # get 'posts/index'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   delete 'posts' => 'posts#destroy'
   root 'posts#index'
```

When I click on the Destroy call on the HTML page in the browser, this is what I get in the log file:

```
Started GET "/posts" for x.x.x.x at 2015-09-12 10:06:10 -0400
Cannot render console from x.x.x.x! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
```

Essentially, the delete controller action never gets called.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Please only share if you understand the issue and can share thoughts on how to fix it.

**Note:**
I have tried posts_path(post) and posts_path in the inde.html.erb file as well (instead of just "posts" but that did not solve the issue).

Also, I did not have "delete 'posts' => 'posts#destroy'" in my route file earlier but I still had the same issue

Update:
 I white listed the IP address but that does not solve the issue.  The URL is not well formed (I think):

```
<td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/posts/1">Destroy</a></td>
```

Comment: why you need this: `resources :posts` and this `delete 'posts' => 'posts#destroy'` ?

Comment: I did not have delete 'posts' => 'posts#destroy' before but it did not work then either

Comment: also, you need the resources :posts, the page does not even load up without it

Comment: did you remove the `javascript_include_tags` from your layout?

Answer (score 0):

By default, only requests coming from IPv4 and IPv6 localhosts are allowed.

You need to whitelist the x.x.x.x network space in the Web Console config. Like this:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
     config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = 'x.x.x.x'
end
```

Reference: https://github.com/rails/web-console#configweb_consolewhitelisted_ips

and you also need this changes:

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :posts
```

And in the posts controller, do this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # ...
    # DELETE /posts/1
    # DELETE /posts/1.json
    def destroy
       @post.destroy

       redirect_to posts_url
    end

    private
        def set_post
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling redirect twice. This will cause rails to throw a double render error. Remove the `redirect_to_posts_url` that's after the respond to block. Your method should look more like this:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
   end
end
```

You can also remove the flash messages, because it is already set by notice `notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.'`

Comment: how does that solve my original question - I only placed the redirect after destroy was not working - and it still is not after removing the lines you mentioned

Comment: my original issue is that the destroy call is not working

Comment: it looks like you may need to whitelist your IP in development.rb: config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = %w( 'x.x.x.x' )